# Suppress printing when reading matrices from a file

Tags: matlab

I have two big matrices in two files, A (21,000 x 80,000) and B(3,000 x 80,000) that I want to multiply:

C = A*B_transposed

Currently I have the following script:

```
A = dlmread('fileA')
B = dlmread('fileB')
C = A*(B')
dlmwrite('result', C)
exit
```

However, reading the matrices (first two lines) takes very long and Matlab (after each dlmread) proceeds to print these matrices. Do you know how to disable this printing and make the process faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To suppress printing you merely need to put a semicolon after each line:

```
A = dlmread('fileA');
B = dlmread('fileB');
dlmwrite('result', A * B');
```

---

One way to speed up the read is to tell Matlab what delimiter you are using, so that it doesn't need to be inferred. For example, if the file is tab delimited you could use

```
A = dlmread('fileA','\t');
```

or if it's comma delimited you could use:

```
A = dlmread('fileA',',');
```

Other than that, you could consider using a different file format. Where are the files generated? If they're generated by another Matlab process, then you could save them in Matlab's binary format, which is accessed using `load` and `save`:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
save('file.mat','A');
clear A;
load('file.mat','A');
```

---

For a quick benchmark, I wrote the following matrix to two files:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> dlmwrite('test.txt',A);
>> save('test.mat','A');
```

I then ran two benchmarks:

```
>> tic; for i=1:1000; dlmread('test.txt',','); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.506136 seconds.
>> tic; for i=1:1000; load('test.mat','A'); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.260381 seconds.
```

Here the version using `load` came in at half the time of the `dlmread` version. You could do your own benchmarking for matrices of the appropriate size and see what works best for you.

Comment: +1: It's worth to note that sometimes `load` takes more time than actually parsing the file. Especially if you need to work on each line independently, without actually having to store the entire contents in memory.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks for that comment! You should definitely benchmark possible solutions and use whichever one works best for your typical usage pattern.